# Swift4 Xcode 10.1 beta 3 NSFetchedResultsControllerがレイアウトの中ほどに置いたUITableViewを認識しない

Tags: ios, swift4, coredata

UIViewControllerでレイアウトの中ほどに置いたTableViewのデータソースをFetchedResultsControllerで管理したいのですがTableViewを認識しません。（下のエラーメッセージ参照）

2018-10-25 16:01:40.151608+0900 Proto5ver2[1101:234061] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "testPortal" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'

ビューコントローラはUIViewControllerで作成しましたが、後からUITableViewControllerに変更し、NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegateを追加しています

import UIKit
import CoreData

class TestPortalViewController: UITableViewController,  NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

・TableView（taskTableView)にはStoryboardで、delegateとdatasourceを指定していますから、これを認識してくれると思ったのですが上手くいきません。

何かを見落としているのでしょうか、アドバイスをお願いいたします。

ちなみに、最初からUITableViewControllerで作成したビューコントローラでは同じコードが動きます。
[image: サブビューの配置][image: サブビューの階層][image: デリゲート＆データソースの指定]

Comment: Storyboardに`UITableViewController`として追加したView Controllerと、単なる`UIViewController`として追加したView Controller(をクラスだけ`UITableViewController`にしたもの)とでは、全く異なった手順で初期化されるため、本来`UITableViewController`が持つはずの`tableView`がうまく初期化できない状態になっているようです。そこらへんの処理内容はブラックボックス化されているため、この状態から確実に動くようにできるものかどうかはよくわかりません。なぜ`UIViewController`のままにしておかれないのでしょうか?

Comment: そもそも`UITableViewController`は、`UITableView`以外のコンテンツが何も(少なくともほとんど)ないことを想定したView Controllerなので、ご提示のように`UITableView`以外のコンテンツが存在する画面には不向きなように思います。Storyboardで変更可能な設定をなんとかしていくことで、画面ロード時にエラーが出ないようにはできましたが、ご提示の画面のような構成を保つことはできませんでした。`UIViewController`として作成したView Controllerを後から`UITableViewController`に変更すると言う実験そのものが目的なのでない限り、`UIViewController`に戻されるべきだと思うのですが。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。私はてっきりNSFetchedResultsControllerはTableViewControllerとペアで使用するものと思い込んでいました。UIViewControllerに戻してUITableViewDataSourceを指定し、FRCのcontroller関連コード中のデータソース名を適応させて動かすことができました。

Comment: なるほど、`UITableViewController`は`UITableView`しかない画面を作るには便利なので、`NSFetchedResultsController`のサンプルコードにはよく使われているのかもしれませんね。事例だけから学習するとどうしてもそういう「思い込んで」は避けにくいかもしれません。「`UIViewController`に戻して」その後適応させるためにしたことなど簡単にまとめて、自己回答してくださるようお願いします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。んが、回答は回答欄にお願いします…。ここスタック・オーバーフローでは、「回答」と「コメント」は別物として区別していますので。

Comment: 解答欄へ移しました、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

自己回答：UIViewControllerでUITableViewとNSFetchedResultsControllerを動かすポイント。

1. ViewControllerの継承

ViewControllerにはUITableViewDataSourceとNSFetchedResultsControllerDelegateを継承させます。ただしMaster-Detail的に作る場合はUITableViewDelegateの継承も必要です。つまりUITableViewControllerを継承するViewControllerとの違いは最初から含まれるか手作業で入れるのかの違いだけです。

2. DataSourceの指定

次にStoryboardに用意するUITableViewをDataSourceとDelegateに指定します。さらにViewControllerのプロパティとしてアウトレット接続します。

3. NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegateの実装

最後にここで付けた名前をNSFetchedResultsControllerDelegateの各プロトコルの実装でデータソース名として使用します。この名前をtableViewにするとDataSourceのプロトコルにも同じ名前のメソッドがあり混乱しがちです。fooTableViewなどの別名を取るのがいいと思います。

以上